# Flutter: How does one generate Raisedbuttons from a list horizontally?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm having this issue where I have a list of options that I want to display within the same row. This piece of code generates the buttons I want, but each button takes up the entire row. This makes it so that the buttons are stacked vertically instead of horizontally. Help?

```
Container(child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
    children: <Widget>[
       Row(children: <Widget>[
         Flexible(
           child: ListView.builder(
              physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: this.item.sizes.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return _sizeButton(index);
              },
           ),
         ),
       ],
       /* SOME OTHER WIDGETS */
     ],
  ),

);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace Row+Flexible with Expanded.

As mentioned, use `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal` too.

https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ec28750de6310c2b4d397250aa9e22d1

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for a `ListView` is to put its items in a vertical list, whereby each item takes up one row. Use `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,` to put the items next to another horizontally.

Comment: Doing this results in white screen with the error, 
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1653 pos 16:
flutter: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add
`scrollDirection = Axis.horizontal`
in ListView.builder

Comment: When I do this- my whole screen goes white. I get the error: 
flutter: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart': Failed assertion: line 1653 pos 16:
flutter: 'constraints.hasBoundedHeight': is not true.

Comment: Wrap the ```ListView.builder``` in a ```Container( height: 44```  you can set it to any height of choice